# Android Facebook SDK doesn't show login screen

Tags: android, facebook, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, facebook-android-sdk

I am using Cocos2dX I have a method in a custom class called login which is invoked by some native code via JNI, this is meant to tell Facebook to login and show the UI. However it doesn't show anything when I am logged out of Facebook.

Class

```
public class AndroidFacebook {

    protected static Activity activity = null;
    protected static Context context = null;

    protected AndroidFacebook() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    public static void init(Activity activity) {
        AndroidFacebook.activity = activity;
        AndroidFacebook.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public static void login() {

        Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(AndroidFacebook.activity);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }

        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(AndroidFacebook.activity)
                .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info"))
                .setCallback(callback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(AndroidFacebook.activity, true, callback);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm trying to integrate C++ through JNI on cocos2dx and have kind of same problem, did you have any success doing it?
Please let me know.
Thanks a lot.
Khash

Comment: I think I did in the end but it was very buggy.

Comment: Hi James, I would appreciate if you can send me the java part of the code, or any hint that can help, I'm getting Error when trying to login.

Comment: I'll upload my code to here https://github.com/NyxDigital/ParseCPP its for Parse but includes code for Faceboo

Comment: Thanks a lot @James, I'll have a look.

Comment: Let me know if naything is missing @Khash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI call is in its separate thread, probably the thread your c++ code is running. If you want to control UI in android, use view.post or Activity.runOnUiThread to make it works.